# Can a LDL decomposition be efficiently converted into UDU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

**Question:**
If you are given matrices $L,D_L$ where
$L$ is a lower unit triangular matrix, $D_L$ is a diagonal matrix, and $L,D_L$ are a LDL decomposition of a particular symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ as,
$$A=LD_LL^T$$
can you calculate matrices $U,D_U$ where
$U$ is an upper unit triangular matrix, $D_U$ is a diagonal matrix, and satisfices
$A=UD_UU^T$? 
Of course, there is a obvious solution by calculating $A$ from $L,D_L$ and then conducting a Cholesky decomposition to acquire $U,D_U$, but can this be done without explicitly calculating $A$?
**Notes:** I found a relation between LDL decomposition and UDU decomposition as
$$UD_UU=(L'^{T})^{-1}(1/D')(L')^{-1}$$
$$A^{-1}=L'D'L'^T$$
which shows that $U,D_U$ can be calculated by solving the LDL decomposition of $A^{-1}$, but I don't know if this is a path to a solution.